# sql query question for most name in table with multiple most names

Tags: mysql

`fbn` table:

```
create table fbn (
id int,
name varchar(40),
birthday date,
gender varchar(10));

INSERT into fbn values
(1, "James", "2000-04-22", "male"),
(2, "Julia", "2006-02-27", "female"),
(3, "Ethan", "2013-05-23", "male"),
(4, "Lion", "2014-09-11", "male"),
(5, "Ethan", "2006-01-01", "male"),
(6, "Lion", "2006-02-01", "male");
```

what's the name that occur most? note that there are two names (Ethan and Lion) occur most often. I have two solutions as below:

```
select tmp2.name 
from (select tmp.name, 
             dense_rank() over(order by tmp.name_count desc) rank
      from (select name, 
                   count(*) name_count 
            from fbn 
            group by name) tmp
      ) tmp2
where tmp2.rank = 1;
```

and the 2nd solution:

```
select name from fbn 
group by name 
having count(name) = (select count(name) from fbn 
                      group by name 
                      order by count(name) desc
                      limit 1);
```

both seem to be working, but both looks like too complicated. is there any other solution that's more concise easier to understand? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT counts,GROUP_CONCAT(NAME) AS names
FROM
(SELECT NAME, COUNT(*) counts  FROM fbn GROUP BY NAME) A 
GROUP BY counts 
ORDER BY counts DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qzmJAx5LFfzZdYyDetUfex/1

Comment: first time to see `group_concat()`. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: Yes, it's a function I like to use a lot and it seems too perfect in your case. This way, as long as anyone who have the same count occurrences, they all going to be shown in the `group_concat` result.

Answer (score 0):

Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY if its enabled using:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Here in inner query provide name with occurrence count. And outer query just use that temporary table to get max count value. Now it will return single row with name & total occurrence(max).

```
SELECT name, MAX(occurrence) 
FROM (SELECT name, COUNT(id) occurrence
FROM fbn
GROUP BY name) t;
```

Comment: it needs to output the name, not the most occurrence. so i think this can be used as subquery and then add one more query to get the name.

Comment: @NicoHaase Updated query to return name. Also added explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply:

```
select count(id) as num_names, name from fbn group by name order by num_names desc limit 1;
```

Comment: can this output the two names that tie regarding most occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

For Ms :

```
select Top 1 count(id) as num_names, name from fbn group by name order by num_names desc
```

Comment: not familiar with sql-server, but can this output two names that tie regarding the most occurrence?

Comment: No.It wont concat the output.